# Grabbing last insert id sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am working on a php code where I insert into two tables and want to grab the id from the first table I inserted into, right now I am getting this error:  `Call to undefined function sqlsrv_field()`. I am trying to grab the `routine_id` from the table `routines`.

Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$date = strftime ('%Y-%m-%d'); 
$time = strftime('%H:%M:%S');


$value = $_GET['Temp'];

$conn = sqlsrv_connect('BILAL' , $conn_array);

$sql = "Insert into routines (date, time, value, emp_id)  values ('$date', '$time', '$value', (SELECT id FROM emps WHERE user_name='Arduino'))";


if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}

$query = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $query === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

sqlsrv_next_result($query);
sqlsrv_fetch($query);
$id = sqlsrv_field($query,0);
$sql2 = "Insert into measure_routines (routine_id, measure_id, pool_id) values ('$id', (Select id from measurements where title='A_Auto_Temperatur'), 1 )";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function lastId($queryID) {
    sqlsrv_next_result($queryID);
    sqlsrv_fetch($queryID);
    return sqlsrv_get_field($queryID, 0);
}

$lastInsertedId = lastId($stmt);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no function called `sqlsrv_field()`. Instead, use [**sqlsrv_get_field()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296207%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
...

sqlsrv_next_result($query);

bool fetchStatus = sqlsrv_fetch($query);

if(fetchStatus === false) {
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if(fetchStatus === null) {
   // Some work when there are no results in the result set
} else {
   $id = sqlsrv_get_field($query, 0);
}

...
```

This should solve your problem basically. However your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead of giving values directly into the sql query, consider using prepared statements.

There are many articles about that, here is one I found in quick search:

- [What's the Right Way to Prevent SQL Injection in PHP Scripts?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/04/what_2700_s-the-right-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-php-scripts_3f00_.aspx)